# Bridging 3G/LTE from cellphone to IOT device

Tags: c, embedded, bluetooth, wearable, cellular

I have an IOT device that needs to function as an access point, even without close by wifi signals, and then publish a wifi network. I know that I can achieve this with a 3G/LTE/GSM module but given this particular IOT device is essentially a wearable (housed in a backpack so weight isn't chief of my concerns) I was hoping there would be a way to bridge the connection of my 3g device over bluetooth or another protocol, connecting my device to the internet that way instead of giving it its own module and sim card.

Answer (score 0):

Connect with regular WLAN to the smartphone with tethering enabled. Examples: ESP8266, ATWINC1500.